# Javers JQL - query by foreign key

Tags: javers

Is it possible to do a "foreign key query" using Javers? I have entity B that references entity A using `entity_a_id`. I'd like to find all changes for entity B that have a value of `entity_a_id` of some value (say 62191).

To be clear, entity B is NOT included as a one-to-many on entity A.  However, the foreign key does exist on entity B.